# How to use FreeRTOS with MPLAB X that runs on a MAC OS

Tags: mplab, freertos

I'm programming my PIC microcontroller on a MAC OS.
Can you use FreeRTOS with MPLAB X running on a MAC OS?

I've noticed [directions](http://www.freertos.org/a00104.html) that include downloading a .exe file, but does that mean it's only good on a windows version of MPLAB X?

---

In the direction for starting, it says to open a demo project and try compiling but I can't open it. Not sure if it's .gld or .mpc or .mcs or .mcw or .mcs, but none of them work.

"[file name] can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer"

---

Also can't include file in project. I right clicked project>properties>general and added the FreeRTOS/Source and FreeRTOS-Plus/Source folders, yet i get the the following error

**Main.c:16:20: fatal error: semphr.h: No such file or directory**

Note: this issue has been resolved by just dragging all FreeRTOS sources and headers to the standard folder. Originally when attempting to include original folders under project>general, by adding the path, didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeRTOS doesn't care about the environment you are using for development. So yes, you can use MacOS when you are developing with it.

The .exe file you are mentioning is a self-extracting ZIP file (at least that's whats mentioned on the page you are linking to), which is also available as [plain ZIP file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freertos/files/latest/download?source=files).

When you are looking at the [supported hardware list](http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#MICROCHIP) you find some examples using MPLAB (for PIC18, 24, dsPic and PIC32). These pre-configured examples may make your start easier.